# primeng header name derived from field in angular2 datatable

Tags: angular, primeng

So I am new to primeng and trying to use the datatable component, previously in angular 1, ui-grid used to provide capability that if you do not describe the header name, it will automatically take the name of field, and not only that if its in camel case, it will automatically fix it for you, i.e i have below code

```
<p-column field="LOSS_EVENT_ID" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
```

it would take header as field, and convert it into **Loss Event Id**, is there any such capability in primeng?

Comment: <p-column field="LOSS_EVENT_ID" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
should be taken as <p-column field="LOSS_EVENT_ID" header="Loss Event Id" [sortable]="true"></p-column>

Comment: if you want to set header you can use like this `<p-column field="LOSS_EVENT_ID"  header='Loss Event Id' [sortable]="true"></p-column>`

Comment: no you have to set header differently , according to me , have a look at the documention

Comment: have you solved with your problem ?

Comment: no i am trying to find a if the datatable will automatically populate header for me